# Unable to obtain children in jest + enzyme react test

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following component:

GenericButton:

```
render() {
    return(
        <span>
            <Button ... props... />
            {this.renderModalIfNeeded()}
        </span>);

}

renderModalIfNeeded() {
    if (this.props.modalConfirm) {
        return <BasicModal ref={(component) => this.modal = component}
                           title="Confirm"
                           body={this.props.modalText}
                           buttons={[
                                        {
                                            id: "Cancel_"+this.props.id,
                                            text : 'Cancel',
                                            style : 'grey'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            id: "Confirm"+this.props.id,
                                            text : 'OK',
                                            action : () => this.props.action()
                                        }
                                    ]}/>;
    }

}
```

BasicModal:

```
renderButtons() {
    return this.props.buttons
                     .map((button) => {
                         const previousAction = button.action;
                         button.action = () => {
                             if (previousAction) {
                                 previousAction();
                             }
                             this.close();
                         };
                         return button;
                     })
                     .map((button, count) => <GenericButton key={"Button_"+count+"_"+this.props.id} {...button} />);
}

render() {
        return (
            <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={::this.close}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>{this.props.title}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {this.props.body}
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    {this.renderButtons()}
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
```

I have this test, in which i am trying to validate that the buttons in the modal are shown properly (the ones in `this.renderButtons()` )

```
describe('Given modal requirements', () => {
            const text = "Ne me mori facias";
            const id = "Generosa";
            const innerModal = mount(<GenericButton id={id} modalConfirm={true} modalText={text}/>).find('BasicModal').first();
            it('has two buttons', () => {
                const cancelButton = <GenericButton id={"Cancel_"+id} text="Cancel" style="grey"/>;
                const okButton = <GenericButton id={"Confirm_"+id} text="OK" action={() => {}} />;

                const extractModalBody = (modal) => {
                  return modal.find('BasicModal').first().find('Modal');
                };
                expect(extractModalBody(innerModal)).toContainReact(cancelButton);
                expect(extractModalBody(innerModal)).toContainReact(okButton);
            });
        });
```

If within the test i try to check the contents of the `BasicModal` component using `.debug()` I get the following:

```
<BasicModal title="Confirm" body="Ne me mori facias" buttons={{...}}>
  <Modal show={false} onHide={[Function]}>
    <Modal show={false} onHide={[Function]} backdrop={true} keyboard={true} autoFocus={true} enforceFocus={true} manager={{...}} renderBackdrop={[Function]} animation={true} dialogComponentClass={[Function]} bsClass="modal">
      <Modal onHide={[Function]} keyboard={true} autoFocus={true} enforceFocus={true} manager={{...}} renderBackdrop={[Function]} show={false} onEntering={[Function]} onExited={[Function]} backdrop={true} backdropClassName="modal-backdrop" containerClassName="modal-open" transition={[Function]} dialogTransitionTimeout={300} backdropTransitionTimeout={150} />
    </Modal>
  </Modal>
</BasicModal>
```

How am i supposed to check that the buttons are actually rendered?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.render()` it returns a cheerio to a React Component DOM rendered ..

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/render.md

In the docs

> ```
> .render() => CheerioWrapper
> ```
>
> Returns a CheerioWrapper around the rendered HTML of the current
>   node's subtree.
>
> Note: can only be called on a wrapper of a single node.
>
> **Returns**
>
> String: The resulting HTML string
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> const wrapper = mount(<Bar />);
> expect(wrapper.find(Foo).render().find('.in-foo')).to.have.length(1);
> ```